# Angular http service displaying tab details depending on Json key

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-http

I am note sure if it is possible but here's what I am trying to do:

I would like to fill empty templates depending from the `td` clicked, for exemple if you clicked on `<td *ngFor="let user of userService.user | async">{{user.data.server1}}</td>` then you move to the server1.component.ts details page witch contains the `server1` Json object details

==> I found things with `requestOptions.params` thats an idea ..so it's like the datas are fetch  by a get request comming from the Json and returning the datas according to the selected row from the tab

Same idea as in php when you do something like this: `<?php
echo $_GET['link'];`

In 1 row = 1 Json object = 1 page (parent with tab and child displaying details from each row)

In other word each clicked row of the tab will be a page displaying plenty details about the choosen Json object (charts, %indicators,)

**NOTE** :  I don't want to code plenty plenty child components for each row, I would like just one child component filling by the different object Json different in each row...

I think using that method it could works maybe [How to pass url arguments (query string) to a HTTP request on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular-2)

My request is also a bit similar to that question, I am actually trying to adapt that code : [Angular http service clear RequestOptions search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249367/angular-http-service-clear-requestoptions-search-parameters)

*Not sure if the routerLink is needed maybe everything is possible with the correct http service configuration*

If anyone got an idea? Thanks in advance...

json:

```
user {
{ data 
  }, {
server1 {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Leanne Graham",
 "username": "Bret",
 "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
 "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
    "city": "Gwenborough",
    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
   },
   server2 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
    "city": "Gwenborough",
    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
   },
 }
}
```

tab.html:

```
<table>
<tr routerLink=""/my-Server1>
   <td *ngFor="let user of userService.user | async">{{user.data.server1}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  users: Observable<User[]>;
    constructor (public http: Http) {
          const tick$ = Observable.timer(100, 60000);

          this.users = tick$.flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL)).map(res => [res.json()]).publishBehavior(<User[]>[]).refCount();
 }
}
```

server1.html :

```
<div ngFor=""let user of userService.user | async"">{{server1.app.id}}
</div>
<div ngFor=""let user of userService.user | async"">{{server1.tol.name}}</div>

<p ngFor="let user of userService.user | async">{{server1.book.51}}</p>
```

..**note** there's plenty other things in the `server1.html` template and plenty other `tr` in the `tab.html`

Comment: it hard to figure out what are you after can you throw some more light on the same ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I updated my post

Comment: do you want to display each row of table in greater detail in the server 1 .html

Comment: @RahulSingh yes something like this.. in fact each row of table will be an app or a service and when you clicked you will have plenty details about the choosen row (charts, %indicators,) returning from an Json

Comment: so what's stopping you on this ?

Comment: @RahulSingh thank you for you request and help... I don't want to code plenty plenty components for each row, I would like just one component filling by the different Json in the different in each row..is that clear enough?

Comment: like you will pass the data to a different component , you make use a parent  child relation ship and use event emitters to pass data to the other component and then in child comp make service call if you need any.

Comment: @RahulSingh I know event emitter and output or input that's not what I am looking for

Comment: what are you looking at ?

Comment: @RahulSingh something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular-2